# GAS: Function to retrieve last row in Google Spreadsheet ADDS columns

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have used this function numerous times to retrieve the last row of data of a Google Spreadsheet, but this time around I am getting some very strange behavior.

I *literally* watch the spreadsheet add columns as this bit of code is running. Eventually I run into the **256** column limit and the execution of my script fails.

I have commented out all of my code and exclusively ran this function and I still run into the same problem.

Has anyone experienced this before, or perhaps has an alternate solution?

```
//Grabs the latest data submission and return it as an array.
function getLastSubmit() {
    //Find the Spreadsheet containing the data we need.
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form Responses");

    //Get the last row and column width of the sheet.
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();

    Logger.log("lastRow=" + lastRow);
    Logger.log("lastColumn=" + lastColumn);

    var range = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 1, 1, lastColumn);
    var values = new Array();

    for (var i = 0; i < lastColumn; i++) {
        Logger.log(range.offset(0, i).getValue());
        values.push(range.offset(0, i).getValue());
    }

    Logger.log("values=" + values);

    //Return the values of the lastRow from 0 to the lastColumn.
    return values;
}
```

Additionally, the Execution Transcript says the following (I am clearly not trying to retrieve data out of range.):

```
[14-02-07 21:13:47:648 MST] Logger.log([, []]) [0 seconds]
[14-02-07 21:13:47:648 MST] Range.offset([0, 116]) [0 seconds]
[14-02-07 21:13:47:702 MST] Range.getValue() [0.053 seconds]
[14-02-07 21:13:47:702 MST] Range.offset([0, 117]) [0 seconds]
[14-02-07 21:13:47:765 MST] Range.getValue() [0.062 seconds]
[14-02-07 21:13:47:773 MST] Execution failed: You can't add any more columns to this sheet. There is a limit of  columns per sheet. To continue working, create a new sheet or a new workbook. For more information on size and complexity limits in Google spreadsheets, visit the <a target=_blank href=>Google Docs Help Center.</a> (line 19, file "Functions") [16.023 seconds total runtime]
```

And my Logger:

```
[14-02-07 21:13:31:908 MST] lastRow=3
[14-02-07 21:13:31:908 MST] lastColumn=140
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `offset` method, if you read the [documentation :](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offset%28Integer,Integer%29)

*offset(rowOffset, columnOffset)
Returns a new range that is offset from this range by the given number of rows and columns (which can be negative). The new range will be the same size as the original range.*

So what you are experiencing is logical since you **move** your selection with index value `i` 
in these 2 lines :

```
        Logger.log(range.offset(0, i).getValue());
        values.push(range.offset(0, i).getValue());
```

I guess you didn't notice it before probably because your sheet was shorter so that it never exceeded the 256 columns limit.